# SQL query for rooms with specific preferences for hotel app

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

Rooms:

```
room_id | room_name | ... 
1       |  regular  | ...
2       |  suite    | ...
          .
```

Preferences:

```
pref_id | pref_kind | ... 
1       |  wi-fi    | ...
2       |  view     | ...
.
```

Rooms_and_preferences:

```
room_id | pref_id  
1       |  1  
1       |  2 
2       |  1  
4       |  4  
4       |  3  
5       |  4   
6       |  1 
     .
```

For example room_1 has 2 preferences, room_2 has only 1 preference, room_3 does not have preferences and so on.

The user chooses preferences and I want to display the rooms that have them. For example:

- if the user dont want preferences I want to be displayed room_3.
- if the user want the preference_1 I want to be displayed room_2, room_6.
- if the user want the preference_1, preference_2 and I want to be displayed room_1.

Suppose I have the required preferences_ids and I want to display the room_ids from table Rooms_and_preferences, what is the SQL query for this?

I have tried this code but doesnt work as i desire:

```
SELECT room_id
FROM Rooms_and_preferences
where pref_id in ( . , . , ...)
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pref_id) = *number of list
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: if for the list i give (1) and count (DISTINCT pref_id)= 1, i will get room_1 ,room_2 and room_6 . I want to only get room_2 and room_6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an *exact* match to the preferences, then this is trickier:

```
SELECT r.room_id
FROM rooms r LEFT JOIN
     Rooms_and_preferences rp
     ON r.room_id = rp.room_id 
GROUP BY r.room_id
HAVING SUM( rp.pref_id IN ( . , . , ...) ) = *number of list* AND
       COUNT(*) = *number of list*;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that rooms with no preferences are included.  The first `HAVING` condition ensures that all matching preferences are included for the room (this assumes no duplicates).  The second `HAVING` condition ensures that there are no extra conditions.

Comment: Yes!! I believe this is exactly what i wanted. Thank you very much!!